# LINQ Causing Invalid Cast?

Tags: c#, linq, error-handling, casting, type-conversion

I am receiving the error at the bottom when executing the provided code. I am brand new to LINQ, but I'm afraid it is casting my `GeographicCode` column into an `int32` even though it is explicitly listed as a `string`. The value will always be an integer in the case of this program, though the field in the database is nvarchar(64) *(and with good reason, not worth explaining but in short, it can't be modified)*

---

### Original Code:

`GeographicalKey` is a string representing a column name, in this case `BranchID`
`GeographicalCode` is a string representing a branch ID, in this case `104`

```
var registrationRows = (from reg in RegistrationData.AsEnumerable()
                        where reg.Field<string>(GeographicalKey) == GeographicCode
                        select reg);
var RegistrationResults = registrationRows.Any() ?  registrationRows.CopyToDataTable() : RegistrationData.Clone();
```

### Error specifically occurs during the line `var RegistrationResults...`

It returns this Error:

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ReferenceField(Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row, String columnName)
   at Leads_Generation.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ExecuteReport>b__0(DataRow model) in u:\Projects\_In Development\Desktop Applications\Leads Generation\Leads Generation\Program.cs:line 83
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Leads_Generation.Program.ExecuteReport(DataTable ModelData, DataTable RegistrationData, String GeographicalTypeQuery, String GeographicalType, String GeographicalKey, String ReportFrequency) in \_In Development\Desktop Applications\Leads Generation\Leads Generation\Program.cs:line 85}
```

---

### Attempted new code suggestion *(Added .ToString() to GeographicalKey)*:

```
var modelRows = (from model in ModelData.AsEnumerable()
                 where model.Field<string>(GeographicalKey).ToString() as string == GeographicCode
                 select model);
DataTable ModelResults = modelRows.Any() ? modelRows.CopyToDataTable() : ModelData.Clone();
```

### Resulted in a new error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Leads_Generation.Program.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ExecuteReport>b__0(DataRow model) in u:\Projects\_In Development\Desktop Applications\Leads Generation\Leads Generation\Program.cs:line 83     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)     at Leads_Generation.Program.ExecuteReport(DataTable ModelData, DataTable RegistrationData, String GeographicalTypeQuery, String GeographicalType, String GeographicalKey, String ReportFrequency) in u:\Projects\_In Development\Desktop Applications\Leads Generation\Leads Generation\Program.cs:line 85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that field is type `Int32` you can't cast `Int32` to `String` however you can convert it to `String`. If error is because of `GeographicalKey` column then following code should fix it.

```
reg.Field<object>(GeographicalKey).ToString() == GeographicCode
```

If you're sure that column is `Int32` you can replace `object` with `Int32`.

To fix `NullReferenceException` you just need a nullity check or use `??` operator like this

```
(reg.Field<object>(GeographicalKey) ?? (object)String.Empty).ToString() == GeographicCode
```

Am not sure whether this compiles but give a try

```
var registrationRows = (from reg in RegistrationData.AsEnumerable()
                        let myField = reg.Field<object>(GeographicalKey)
                        where myField!=null && myField.ToString() == GeographicCode
                        select reg);
```

Comment: didn't work. Resulted in a new error. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Okay, that worked, but really? Is there possibly a more elegant way to arrive at this? The code is really quite unreadable from a future developer standpoint. It's looks pretty atrocious. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned, your field *GeographicalKey* is an integer and you're trying to cast it to a string. If *GeographicCode* will always hold an integer value, perhaps it is much better to do the opposite, that is to convert *GeographicCode* to integer:

```
int GeographicNum = Convert.ToInt32(GeographicCode);
var modelRows = (from model in ModelData.AsEnumerable()
                 where model.Field<int>(GeographicalKey) == GeographicNum
                 select model);
```

This code is more elegant and performs better.

**EDIT**

If *GeographicCode* can sometimes be a value that does not convert to an integer, then we know in advance running the query will result in nothing being returned, because *GeographicalKey* is an integer and comparing it to a non-integral value will return false. So we'd better off not running the query altogether in those cases to save time and resources:

```
int GeographicNum;
If(int.TryParse(GeographicCode, out GeographicNum) {
    var modelRows = (from model in ModelData.AsEnumerable()
                     where model.Field<int>(GeographicalKey) == GeographicNum
                     select model);
}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, BUT unfortunately that snippet of code is from a generic method that is typically a string for the `GeographicCode`. Modify it to resemble this and BOOM, the other 75% of the time the code would fail due to a conversion from `string`. Good idea though.

Comment: So, are you saying that `GeographicCode` will in "75% of the time" have a value that cannot convert to and integer? Well, then your LINQ query will return nothing and there is no point in wasting the time and resources running it. See my edit in a moment.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding. GeographicCode is an alpha numeric field. Sometimes, the value might be an integer *(such as 104)* other times it might have a code *(such as FX)*. It has to remain a string, the computer just has instances where all strings it grabs happen to be numeric and I believe this is cause confusion in the LINQ statement.

Comment: I'm not sure how your explanation changes anything. Firstly, in the code I suggested, the value and type of `GeographicCode` is kept as is, a string. I used a different variable `GeographicNum` to hold the converted value. Secondly, when `GeographicCode = "FX"` in your example, what do you expect your LINQ query to return? Obviously, nothing since `GeographicalKey` holds an integer. It is like you're saying `where 104 = "FX"`.

Comment: No, reread the question. It is saying where `BranchID` = `104` OR where `BranchID` = `FX`. Also, in the question it says `<string>`, NOT integer.

Comment: What??? Where does it say `BranchID = 104 OR where BranchID = FX`? I don't see that. Now, yes you mentioned `<string>`, but you're clearly getting the error because it is an integer NOT string. If it is `nvarchar` in the database like you mentioned, then perhaps your `ModelData` is incorrect and you need to change it there from integer to string which will solve your issue without a need for casting.